# Update statement for sqlite in python not working

Tags: python, sqlite

I have made a simple for loop program which takes info from the user and updates the Database in sqlite. However my program does not update the DB, it just plainly ignores it. I have tried solutions from all over the net and haven't found anything just yet. **I've given just the relevant stuff everything else works just fine**.

```
query ="Alpha"

string = "Beta"

CreateDB = sqlite3.connect('check.db')
querycurs = CreateDB.cursor()

def createTable():
    querycurs.execute('''CREATE TABLE Data1
                         (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, q TEXT, info TEXT)''')

createTable()

def addCust(q,info):
    querycurs.execute('''INSERT INTO Data1 (q,info)
                         VALUES (?,?)''',(q,info))

addCust(query,string)

for i in range (1, 5):
    string = input('What would you like to enter?: ')
    querycurs.execute('UPDATE Data1 SET info =? WHERE q =?',(string,query))
    CreateDB.commit()
```

If you get any syntax errors running this program its fine cause i edited the program so i could put it online. It's only the UPDATE statement you'd need to worry about. Cheerio.

Comment: I have tried your code on my PC and it works fine. The database is updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine for me. I suggest you change `input()` to `raw_input()` to enforce string data.